# How to deduce the output_node_names of a pretrained model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm trying to convert a pretrained model for us with Tensorflow.js:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

I chose `mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco`.

`tensorflowjs_converter` expects specific `output_node_names`. Various resources on the web point me to tools like [`summarize_graph`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#inspecting-graphs) to help with inspecting potential output node names.

Unfortunately, I'm running this on Google Colab, and (from what I can tell) I can't install bazel, which I need to build `summarize_graph` from source, which I need to identify which `output_node_names` to pass to the converter.

Am I missing something here? Is there a more straight forward way to go from an existing pretrained model to Tensorflow.js (for inference on the browser)?

Answer (score 0):

For mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28 the result of
`bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph --in_graph=frozen_inference_graph.pb`
is

```
Found 1 possible inputs: (name=image_tensor, type=uint8(4), shape=[?,?,?,3])
No variables spotted.
Found 5 possible outputs: (name=detection_boxes, op=Identity) (name=detection_scores, op=Identity) (name=detection_classes, op=Identity) (name=num_detections, op=Identity) (name=detection_masks, op=Identity)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to run bazel on Google colab?

Comment: No, I do not think you will be able to run bazel on google colab since it is not a fully functioning linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me:
https://developer.arm.com/technologies/machine-learning-on-arm/developer-material/how-to-guides/optimizing-neural-networks-for-mobile-and-embedded-devices-with-tensorflow/determine-the-names-of-input-and-output-nodes

Get tensorboard up and running (can be done in windows or whatever, this is an ubuntu install)

```
pip install tensorboard
```

>

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorboard
```

>

```
python tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py --model_dir resnetv1_50.pb --log_dir /tmp/tensorboard
```

(if you don't have import_pb_to_tensorboard.py you can just download file https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py and point to on whatever directory you save it)

You use the above command to import you model into the tensorboard you are serving. In tensorboard you can click into the model and see what the final output is called. Mine is called "import/final_result"

[image]